# Number column in Oracle table storing 'hidden' decimal places

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, number-formatting

First ever question here, because searching for these terms is way too vague.  I don't know how the data got in to the table (I think just by "insert into tomtest(test) values (280.1);" but can't be sure) but this example seems odd.  Why does the straight select show 1 decimal place, but the to_char select shows 14 decimal places?

```
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> describe tomtest
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
 TEST                                                           NUMBER

SQL> select * from tomtest;

      TEST
----------
     280.1

SQL> select * from tomtest where test = 280.1;

no rows selected

SQL> select to_char(test) from tomtest;

TO_CHAR(TEST)
----------------------------------------
280.10000000000002

SQL> SELECT data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TOMTEST' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TEST';

DATA_TYPE DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
NUMBER          22
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output from `SELECT data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale FROM   USER_TAB_COLS WHERE  TABLE_NAME  = 'TOMTEST' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TEST';`? Or, alternatively, include the DDL statement you used to create the table and the DML statement you used to insert the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the default numberformat in sql plus.
in the database you have the value `280.10000000000002` and not `280.1`

here is an example

```
SQL> select 128.000000000000000000006 as test from dual;

test
-------------------------
                      128

SQL> select 128.200000000000000000006 as test from dual;

test
-------------------------
                    128,2
```

you can change the number format   and check again

```
SQL> SET NUMF 999999999.99999999999999999999999999999999
SQL> select 128.200000000000000000006 as test from dual;

test
-------------------------------------------
       128.20000000000000000000600000000000

SQL>
```

**Update:**
This phenomenon can be explained by the fact that your data type is only defined as a number, without precise specification of precision.
This means that you can save a decimal number, but do not give an exact specification of the decimal places.

Here is an example that shows the differences.

```
CREATE TABLE test_num(
n1 NUMBER,
n2 NUMBER(23,15));

INSERT INTO test_num VALUES(208.20000000000006,208.20000000000006);

SELECT t.*FROM test_num t;
```

Resut in PLSQL/Developer:

```
N      N2
---    ---
208,2  208,200000000000030
```

in plsql Developer you can display numbers as char.  If you want to that activate a checkbox in the preferences: `Tools -> Preferences -> SQL Window -> Number fields to_char`

in your case, I would round a number value to a certain number of decimal places on insert/update or change your data type from `number` to `number(p, s)` (Where p is the precision and s is the scale.)

Comment: Thank you!  I had run the query in Toad and PL/SQL Developer, and they both displayed 280.1 as well, so I *assumed* something else must be going on.  Now I just need to figure out how to change the NUMF in those other tools :¬)